# GEt DSR neighbor node

Tags: ns2

i am working in ns2 DSR protocol. i wnt to learn how to get neighbor node in DSR protocol and how to get Routing table in DSR.  please help me

advance thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the addRoute function defined under mobicache.cc to display the cache contents..a simple printf statement will display all the routes each time the addRoute function is called:

```
path &p = cache[0];
printf("%s %d %s", routecache->net_id.dump(), p.length(), p.dump());
```